# Cannot get the main text of my site to be beside the side menu, like the heading and other info

Tags: html, css

Here is the code I am sure it is something simple in the css but I have tried aligning the text and indenting it but it didnt do anything, but I would like the heading to be to the left close to the menu

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>ConCoder</title>
<link href="sideMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" >
</head>

<body>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="index.html" class="selected"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i> Post Jobs</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Type 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Browse Jobs</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Type 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Contact</a></li>
    <li class="login"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Login</a>
      <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
        <fieldset>
          <label for="email">Username</label>
          <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Username">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
          <label for="remember" class="pure-checkbox">
          <button class="pure-button ">Sign In</button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<h1>Test</h1>

</body>
</html>

side-menu.css
body {
    background-color: #A3A3A3;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
}
nav {
    background: #666;
    padding-top: 12em;
    width: 12em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul a:hover, ul a:focus {
    background-color: #333;
}
nav ul li {
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 3em;
    color: #A3A3A3;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li ul {
    width: 10em;
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10em;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
}
nav ul li ul:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
nav ul li ul li:first-child a:hover {
    border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
}
nav ul li ul li:last-child a:hover {
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 0;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
a.selected {
    background-color: #33F;
}
.pure-form {
    padding-left: 2em;
    width: 13em;
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15em;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
.login:hover .pure-form {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: which heading you are talking about?

Comment: The test heading outside of the <nav>

Comment: I know its behind the side menu but I cant figure out how to move it over to be visible

Answer (score 0):

Just add the position relative or absolute and you will see that Test heading:
  `<h1 style="position:relative;">Test</h1>`

Comment: thnks for responding! I tried this and it only puts the heading overtop of the side menu but I just figured it out! '<h1 stlye="padding-left:16em">Test</h1>'